# SCSS and Html how to make a line sticky ot the bottom of box whatever the size of text is?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a line that is shown in a div when this div is active. The scss class is:

```
.active-tab:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  right: -7px;
  background-color: $primary;
}
```

The result is as following:

[image]

What I want is the line to stick at the bottom whatever the size of the text is.

Comment: Could you add your HTML? A snippet would be great

Comment: position it absolutely?

Comment: position absolute with a bottom 0 (or whatever) and make sure active-tab is position relative. I would also create a padding bottom the same height as the line for a gutter for it to rest in so it doesnt cover content

Answer (score 1):

Though, I have not added "JS" to add classes, but rest this should work fine.

```css
.active-tab:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  right: -7px;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

span {

}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="vehicleInfo active-tab"> <span>Vehicle Info</span> </div>
<div class="trafficViolation active-tab"> <span>Traffic Violation</span> </div>
</section>
```